# Regex to remove specific words

Tags: regex

I want to without words of abc: with def:

Only want to match "22" "46"

How can without that words?

[image]

Comment: no effort spent. SO is not a free coding service

Comment: You should include some regex directly inside the question instead of this screenshot. Please [edit] your question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please always provide source code, error messages and other textual information as inline plain text rather than external pictures. Text is searchable, reusable and normally easier to read.  If you absolutely need to post a picture, at least don't pad it with extraneous whitespace.

Comment: Do you want to match only the numbers, or capture the values of the key/value pairs? Don't you care about what the values mean?

Answer (score 0):

Although you did not specify much information, you may use the regex below, it matches only the numbers :

```
[^"A-z: ]+
```

or use  :

```
\d+
```

Comment: You assume the OP wants the numbers. I assume he wants the values of the key/value pairs. It's impossible to answer such vague questions